# YAML File validation and integration with CI/CD

Tags: yaml, cicd

I want to add a feature where my YAML file is validated in my pipeline before execution of commands and running the file on my kubernetes cluster. Are there any tools or products that would support this?

Comment: what is the cicd tool that you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [yamllint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#installing-yamllint) to validate yaml files. If you are using `gitlab.com`, then check [this link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html)